# what is the equivalent of 'sequence' in xsd schema (but without ordering)

Tags: xsd

I have some types with a sequence inside, which does restrict the order of child elements. I want to remove these order restrictions. Which element should I choose, assuming that I can't (or don't want) change definition of child elements? 
For example, if I'd change with `<xs:choise maxOccurs="unbounded">` it won't be full equivalent of `<xs:sequence>`, because some child elements which initially supposed to appear only once, could appear now several times.
And vice-versa, I can't use `xs:all`, as now I'll have a restriction on maximum amount of elements (no more than 1).

So, is there simple and quick solution? (to make as few changes to schema as possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is you can't.

An option would be to define a type for each combination of node sequences which are possible and then enclose them in an  but this would be faintly ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `<sequence>` in a `<choice>`.

```
<choice>
  <sequence>
    <!-- list your choices here -->
  </sequence>
</choice>
```